# HackerRank Game of Thrones

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to solve this problem on HackerRank and I am having a issue with my logic. I am confused and not able to think what I'm doing wrong, feels like I'm stuck in logic.

Question link: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/game-of-thrones/

I created a dictionary of alphabets with value 0. And then counting number of times the alphabet appears in the string. If there are more than 1 alphabet characters occurring 1 times in string, then obviously that string cannot become a palindrome. That's my logic, however it only pass 10/21 test cases.

Here's my code:

```
def gameOfThrones(s):
    alpha_dict = {chr(x): 0 for x in range(97,123)}
    counter = 0
    
    for i in s:
        if i in alpha_dict:
            alpha_dict[i] += 1
            
    for key in alpha_dict.values():
        if key == 1:
            counter += 1
    
    if counter <= 1:
        return 'YES'
    else:
       return 'NO'
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: In such problems, first try to find case where your algorithm will fail, let me help you with example: `aaab`.
So basically, you only looking for cases with 1, but what about other odd numbers?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that people can try to reproduce faulty behaviour? Also, please [edit] your question to set the title to something meaningful on its own.

Comment: Thanks a lot @kadewu. I understood where I was going wrong. Therefore I changed `if key % 2 == 1:` and it solved my problem. Thanks again dude!

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Sorry for the title, but comments helped me solve my problem.

Comment: @ShivamTawari : Can you show the input you are reading and expected output

Comment: @yyy62103 I got the correct logic, still the input is [here](https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/745/input03.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAR6O7GJNX5DNFO3PV&Expires=1667644923&Signature=uyC28%2B1wcSkXqFRMWzuG%2BMG62cw%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain) and output is **NO**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrected the logic in my solution. I was just comparing `key == 1` and not with every odd element.

So the corrected code looks like:

```
for key in alpha_dict.values():
    if key % 2 == 1:
        counter += 1
```

It passes all the testcases on HackerRank website.

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

The issue is that the code doesn't really look for palindromes. Let's step through it with a sample text based on a valid one that they gave: `aaabbbbb` (the only difference between this and their example is that there is an extra `b`).

Your first for loop counts how many times the letters appear in the string. In this case, 3 `a` and 5 `b` with all the other characters showing up 0 times (quick aside, the end of the `range` function is exclusive so this would not count any z characters that might show up).

The next for loop counts how many character there are that show up only once in the string. This string is made up of multiple `a` and `b` characters, more than the check that you have for `if key == 1` so it doesn't trigger it. Since the count is less than 1, it returns `YES` and exits. However `aaabbbbb` is not a palindrome unscrambled.

### Suggestion

To fix it, I would suggest having more than just one function so you can break down exactly what you need. For example, you can have a function that would return a list of all the unscrambled possibilities.

```
def allUnscrambled(string)->list:
    # find all possible iterations of the string
    # if given 'aabb', return 'aabb', 'abab', 'abba', 'bbaa', 'baba', 'baab'
    return lstOfStrings
```

After this, create a palindrome checker. You can use the one shown by [Dmitriy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74325695/12771942) or create your own.

```
def checkIfPalindrome(string)->bool:
    # determine if the given string is a palindrome
    return isOrNotPalindrome
```

Put the two together to get a function that will, given a list of strings, determine if at least one of them is a palindrome. If it is, that means the original string is an anagrammed palindrome.

```
def palindromeInList(lst)->bool:
    # given the list of strings from allUnscrambled(str), is any of them a palindrome?
    return isPalindromeInList
```

Your function `gameOfThrones(s)` can then call this `palindromeInList( allUnscrambled(s) )` and then return `YES` or `NO` depending on the result. Breaking it up into smaller pieces and delegating tasks is usually a good way to handle these problems.

Comment: First of all, code doesn't need to look for palindromes, and that wasn't issue with the code provided in the question. Second, statement `Breaking it up into smaller pieces and delegating tasks is usually a good way to handle these problems.` Is incorrect, as your approach is O(n!), when to solve the task you just need O(n).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I solved my issue with `if key % 2 == 1:`, as I wasn't able to think beyond some point in my logic but @kadewu's comment helped me solved it.

Answer (score 0):

The property that you have to check on the input string is that the number of characters with odd repetitions must be less than 1. So, the main ingredients to cook you recipe are:

- a counter for each character
- an hash map to store the counters, having the characters as keys
- iterate over the input string

A plain implementation could be:

```py
def gameOfThrones(s):
    counters = {}
    for c in s:
        counters[c] = counters.get(c, 0) + 1
    n_odd_characters = sum(v % 2 for v in counters.values())
```

Using a functional approach, based on [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) from `functools`:

```py
from functools import reduce

def gamesOfThrones(s):
    return ['NO', 'YES'][len(reduce(
        lambda x, y: (x | {y: 1}) if y not in x else (x.pop(y) and x),
        s,
        {}
    )) <= 1]
```

If you want, you can use the [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class from `collections` to make your code more concise:

```py
def gamesOfThrones(s):
    return ['NO', 'YES'][sum([v % 2 for v in Counter(s).values() ]) <= 1]
```